# Replacing single double quote in string in python

Tags: python, string, replace, double-quotes

Given string is:

```
str1=
     "sentence1 and  
           sentence2",
     "sentence3 and 
           sentence4",
     "sentence5 and
           sentence6"
```

desired output is:

```
sentence1 and  
         sentence2;
sentence3 and 
         sentence4;
sentence5 and
         sentence6;
```

> Edited pythod code that i am using now :

```
       if (replace_string.find('",')!=-1):
                 replace_string=replace_string.replace('",', ';');
                 replace_string=replace_string.replace('"','');
```

> it gives me data as below ,find works fine and replacing ", with ; also works fine but now i want 
>   to get rid of the single double quotes as shown below
>   seems like replace_string=replace_string.replace('"',''); is not removing those single double 
>   quotes in beginning of each sentence

"sentence1 and
             sentence2;
    "sentence3 and 
             sentence4;
    "sentence5 and
             sentence6"

Comment: something like replace("\"",";")

Comment: You have to first do `replace('",',';')` and then `replace('"','')`

Answer (score 0):

If the string is assigned in paragraph format. Then it is advised to use the triple quotes. like this.

```
str1 = """
"sentence1 and  
      sentence2",
"sentence3 and 
      sentence4",
"sentence5 and
      sentence6"
"""
```

And then Use

```
str1 = str1.replace(r'",', r";") # this replaces ", with ;
str1 = str1.replace(r'"', '') # this replaces " with nothing.
print str1
```

With respect to the other query:

```
str1.find("",")!=-1 doesnt work to find ",
```

It will not work because it is treating as two parameters being passed to the find function one is empty string and other is only opening double quotes and no ending double quotes.

In such cases you can either use raw string by using r'";' or use the escape character like this "\";"

Comment: thanks ..i have edited the question ..now it works to find ", but i am getting output like the one after edited in above question

Answer (score 0):

**replace** method does not make a replacement in the same string, strings are immutable, so it creates a new string - which, not being assigned to a variable, is lost. Conversion is redundant too - you already have a string.
Just

```
for idx, line in enumerate(my_list):
    my_list[idx] = line.replace('",', ';'.replace('"', '')
```

And try not to use names of Python objects - like *list* - as variable name - lt's a receipe for trouble

**EDIT:**
As for "find not working" - the way you wrote it, you should have get an exception. To make things worth (missed that one), you use Python **str** object instead of **str1**! If you want a double quote within a quoted string, you may:

- Escape it with backslash

  str1.find("\",")!=-1
- Just use single quotes for the string

  str1.find('",')!=-1

Comment: thanks a lot for pointing out i have edited the code ..my find method does not work for ", ..if you could help me with that as well

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
str1 = str1.replace('",', ';')
```

You're missing the assignment.